# Aggregate Query Mongodb for Rating System

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have 2 collections one is user and other is college. I want a rating schema with aggregate query user 1 gives 2 rating to college 1
I made a rating schema like

```
rate = mongoose.Schema({
rating: number,
userId: 
collegeid:})
```

college comes on the basis of score user gets. And then user is allowed to rate the colleges, he has been shown.

So how to write the query to fetch the rating. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is not working?   Are you asking how to do a basic `find()` (or `aggregate()`) to lookup a rating given a college ID or a user ID or both...?

Comment: I have tried find but stuck in aggregate function , can you help me with aggregate to lookup a rating for both @BuzzMoschetti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the `rate` collection has data like this:

```js
var r = [
    { rating: 1, userId: "U1", collegeid: "C1" },
    { rating: 1, userId: "U1", collegeid: "C2" },
    { rating: 3, userId: "U1", collegeid: "C3" },
    { rating: 2, userId: "U2", collegeid: "C1" },
    { rating: 6, userId: "U2", collegeid: "C2" },
    { rating: 7, userId: "U3", collegeid: "C1" },
    { rating: 5, userId: "U3", collegeid: "C4" },
    { rating: 3, userId: "U3", collegeid: "C3" }
];
```

Here are some useful queries to get started.  In general, `aggregate()` is The New `find()` (since at least v3.2) and although slightly more complicated for the simplest expressions, it is vastly more powerful and it should be your starting point.

```js
// Lookup all ratings available for collegeid C1:                                         
c=db.rate.aggregate([
    {$match: {"collegeid":"C1"}}
]);

// Lookup all ratings by user U3:                                                         
c=db.rate.aggregate([
    {$match: {"userId":"U3"}}
]);

// Lookup all ratings by user U3 for college C1:                                          
c=db.rate.aggregate([
    {$match: {"userId":"U3","collegeid":"C1"}}
]);

// Lookup all ratings by user U3 OR college C1:                                           
c=db.rate.aggregate([
    {$match: {$or: [
        {"userId":"U3"},
        {"collegeid":"C1"}
    ]}}
]);

// Get counts, avg, max & min ratings for all colleges:                                   
c=db.rate.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:"$collegeid", n:{$sum:1},
          avg:{$avg:"$rating"},
          max:{$max:"$rating"},
          min:{$min:"$rating"}}}
]);

// Who rated colleges the highest?                                                        
c=db.rate.aggregate([
    {$sort: {"rating":-1}},  // sort descending

    // Use $first operator to capture only the first item for each unique collegeid
    // in the sorted material flowing into this stage:
    {$group: {_id:"$collegeid", who:{$first:"$userId"}, rating:{$first:"$rating"} }}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding so quick. I am trying this. Hey thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in mongoose populate function if you define your Schema correctly.

Please check the link below

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

The "mongoose" way would look something like

```
    ratingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        rating: Number,
        userId: {
            ref: 'users', // Name of the collection that you would like to link to
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId // I Just added the object ID type you could use 
            // a string or whatever your id is
        },
        collegeId: {
            ref: 'colleges', // Name of the collection that you would like to link to
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId
        },
    })

const Rating = mongoose.model('rating', ratingSchema);
```

And then you can use

```
Rating
    .findOne({})
    .populate('userId')
    .populate('collegeId');
```

It is good however to read up and learn about the aggregate pipeline, but mongoose can do a lot of heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thanks can you give me the sample code for this @CalvinCoomer. I am unable to relate how to connect userid and college id with rating.

Comment: its nice and short i will refer this somewhere in between